# I can't create a new folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a sub folder in Download folder named video.Whenever i go to create a new folder in the video folder, it shows this:
[image: "Destination Folder Access Denied. You need to confirm this operation."]
I can't create a new folder in this folder as an admin though i have all permission of the folder but if i change the name of the folder from "Video" to anything then i can do everything i want.But need the folder in that name.

If i pressed continue,then it shows:
[image: Try Again]

Comment: My advice is you should delete the copy from Stack Overflow. It's off-topic there anyway.

Comment: What have you tried? (and where have you copied this question from without even looking at what you're pasting?)

Comment: Take ownership of the file then delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

This message says you don't have the privilege to create you need to change NTFS permission to this folder.

Firstly log-in as **local administrator** if **it been activated*** if not go  then go to the folder you want  and right click on it , then this menu will appear choose proprieties [image]     , then you will get screen choose security  [image]

this will show you the user account(s)  , choose the user you want and click edit
lastly here where you can control the folder permissions write , read ......
now give your user the full control permission so you can add and delete any sub-folders.
[image]